# What's wrong with my logic in my adder-subtractor?

Tags: adder

I'm trying to create an adder-subtracter using only one adder, not gate, and multiplexer. When A = 1000, B = 0001 it results in Q = 0111. If my math is right, that is 8 +(-1) = 7 and 7 = 0111 which is indeed what Q outputs. Now, if I try to switch the values in my circuit as I do in the circuit below I get Q = 1001. Going over my math again A = 1, B = 8 so 1+(-8) = -7 and -7 = 1111 which does not equal the Q output. I'm really confused as to where I went wrong here.

[image: My Circuit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> -7 = 1111

In 4-bit two's complement, -7 would be found by inverting 0111 to get 1000. Then add 1 to get 1001.

So 1001  is indeed the representation of -7 in your system.

1111 is the representation of -7 in 4-bit sign-magnitude so that might be where you got mixed up.